# Adding items without overwriting Document in Firebase/firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an user Inventory using React js and firestore.

My document has a field for "items" which has an array. I want to add items into the array through updateDoc() but I don't know how to add the data without overwriting(erasing) the already existing items in the array.

I wish to add more properties to the items, which would make my structure look like:

User>Username>items>item>value

Or maybe I should use collections for the items? I plan to create a User for each new player and they will have a bunch of items and a bunch of properties. So I would appreciate all kinds of performance suggestion.

[image: This is my Structure]

Answer (score 3):

There's a method in Firestore library ([doc for v8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#arrayunion)) called  `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion()` where you can add more items to an array. It works with `set()` and `update()`.

[Here you have some examples in the official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Another simpler method if you wish to start easier, you could retrieve the document, handle the push of the new object in your javascript/React app, and set the document again. To try at first it's fine, but I'll definitely recommend the first solution if you want to stick with arrays.